# Touchpad shortcut issues in Gnome 3.16 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: touchpad, ubuntu-gnome

First, why is it when I press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> that my touchpad doesn't shut off, even though Gnome 3 says it did in its indicator pop-up?

EDIT: After upgrade to 16.04, problem persists. Crap.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with GNOME on Arch Linux on my Latitude E7240. The touchpad is not disabled while typing and I'm unable to disable it with Fn + F5, although it shows HUD indicators that the touchpad was disabled/enabled it's always enabled.

Comment: At least I know it's a bug now. :P

Comment: I actually found you install a certain package that one of the Ubuntu GNOME devs recommended me to (from the repositories), it's mentioned in the comments of the recent OMG Ubuntu post about upgrading to GNOME 3.20 on 16.04. Also seems to fix a bug where the touchpad settings menu is missing on 3.20, whiuch was the problem a guy wanted to fix and the Ubuntu GNOME dev made the recommendation. (proof the guy is a dev: he talks in a way like as if he's one of the Ubuntu GNOME devs)